# What is the meaning of "front" in "Left Front" or "Right Front"?

Tags: word-meaning, british-english

Generally "front" is a word that refers to standing in the first position.
What is meant by "Front" in situations like "Left Front" and "Right Front", or all these coalition governments that come to power?

Comment: It's in the dictionary, But you might have to scroll down https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/front   **a group of people sharing a political belief who perform actions in public to achieve their aims**